# How to prevent Selenium FF driver to refresh the page when using driver.SwitchTo()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Context**

My automation scenario is opening a page in the first tab, iterating on its links and opening one by one in the second tab, processing one, then close the second one. All works, I can successfully switch to the opening new second tabs, then close them and switch back to the first using:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handleToSwitch)
```

**Issue**

I noticed, that when I switching back to the first window it refreshes, and this is exactly what I did not want, I do not want to navigate (or refresh) this page 100 times, just one. Btw when I switch to the second tab, that is also refreshes what means double time, it is already loaded when I opened that tab.

**Question**

How to prevent refresh the window when navigating and using     `driver.SwitchTo().Window(handleToSwitch)`?

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried to omit the SwitchTo() for example after closing the second tab, thinking that the first tab will be the "current" anyway. This is not working, because when I try to use the page elements, I got "Browser context lost", which I understand. Still I think the refresh is overkill after switch.

Comment: Maybe that site refreshes page by itself? When you manually doing the same actions, page also refreshes?

Comment: Many thanks for asking: No, when doing manually then no refresh occurs. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
((JavascriptExecutor)localDriver).executeScript("window.stop();");
```

immediately after

```
localDriver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
```